# Errors with table names in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms, intellisense

I am brand spanking new to SQL Server and programming itself. So bear with me please.

I have a database called ex. "name" and my query code for it and it executes just fine but all the table names in the query are red. It is only with this specific database. I have another query with a different database with no errors and it runs fine as well. Thank you

Comment: The query runs? Press shift-ctrl-r - specifically: the intellisense cache is outdated and needs to be refreshed. Good from you to identify this as NOT a sql server issue but a management studio issue.

Comment: I agree with TomTom.

Comment: Thank you guys so very much, that was annoying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are cases where the local cache used by IntelliSense becomes stale.

Refreshing the cache is easy but not necessarily obvious.

There are two ways to refresh the cache:

> 1) Go to Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local Cache and
>
> 2) Hit Ctrl+Shift+R.

Comment: Thank you much for taking the time to check it!

Comment: Mark it as answered if it helped :)

Comment: Yes, I'm looking around for that, and what number mean between the arrows?

Comment: Do I give someone points or something? I'm trying to find where I give credit.

Comment: Check the box below the arrows, that will mark the question as answered.

Comment: @truevc73 - the up and down arrows show upvote and downvote, but for that you need enough reputation in the community. :)